# How to reduce the left-padding of a table cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-spacing

I'm highlighting a table cell by shading it. However, the left-padding is exaggerated. How can I reduce that spacing, that leads to a larger grayed area on the left?

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
3.1544 & 1.9929     & 2.6229\\
3.1140 & 1.6107     & 2.4226 \\
12.40208    & 5.92132   & \cellcolor{gray!30} 9.41145 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In my actual document it's an siunitx `S` column, in case that matters.

Comment: Remove the space between `{gray!30}` and `9.41145`.

Comment: @SandyG Thank you! This made the spacing smaller, same size as the spacing to the right. I would like it even smaller, any idea how I could achieve that? Adding a negative space to each cell in the column seems a bit hacky.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `nicematrix` (and `tikz`) you can set precisely the `inner ysep` and `inner xsep`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{highlight/.style={fill=gray!30, inner ysep=1pt, inner xsep=2pt, fit=#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{rrr}
\CodeBefore [create-cell-nodes]
    \tikz{\node[highlight=(3-3)]{};}
\Body
3.1544 & 1.9929     & 2.6229\\
3.1140 & 1.6107     & 2.4226 \\
12.40208 & 5.92132  & 9.41145
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This both solved my problem and introduced me to nicematrix.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `\colorbox` instead of `\cellcolor`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % for '\colorbox' macro
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs}% for '\toprule' and '\bottomrule' macros

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.15}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=4}

\begin{tabular}{@{} S[table-format=2.4] S[table-format=1.4] S[table-format=1.4] @{}}
\toprule
 3.1544   & 1.9929   & 2.6229\\
 3.1140   & 1.6107   & 2.4226 \\
12.40208  & 5.92132  & \colorbox{gray!30}{9.4115} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```